# Single UIView in UIScrollview on each page

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I want to create 10 **UIViews** with **UIButtons** and **UILabels** in a scrollview with paging enabled.

I want to reuse view on each page of scrollview. I don't want to create 10 views using loop.

How can I do it?

And another question. I want to give some animation effect on previous and next view while scrolling. so how can I identify the view?

Comment: Create only 3 `UIView` and maintain them with `Previous next` functionality.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma:I have done that task using swipegesturerecognizer but I want animation effect of paging of UIScrollview which I am not able to get in gesturerecoginzer

Comment: use `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView `  method and enable `Paging` of `UIScrollview` and at change time you can give `Animation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use 3 `UIView`s - one for currently displaying view, one for previous and one for next view. While scrolling, I'd update frames of these views (or constraints), for example:

1. Initial state:

   - 'Previous view' frame: `(-100, 0, 100, 100)`
   - 'Current view' frame: `(0, 0, 100, 100)`
   - 'Next view' frame: `(100, 0, 100, 100)`
2. After scrolling for one page:

   - 'Previous view' frame: `(0, 0, 100, 100)`
   - 'Current view' frame: `(100, 0, 100, 100)`
   - 'Next view' frame: `(200, 0, 100, 100)`

These views are only for displaying purpose, so there is no need to identify the views themselves; I only need to have a current page index and also I need to update each view after page scrolling with content data basing on a data model, e.g. array elements with the following indexes: `(currentPageIndex - 1)`, `currentPageIndex`, `(currentPageIndex + 1)`.

Comment: Are you talking about using swipeGestureRecognizer?

Comment: I got your point. Same kind of code I have implemented using swipeGestureRecognizer but how can I perform this task using UIScrollView?

Comment: I'm talking about using `UIScrollView` with the `pagingEnabled` property set to `YES`. If you use this then you don't need any swipe gesture recognizers - scroll view has built-in gesture recognizer which handles swiping for you.

Comment: So after scrolling my 'current view' will be 'previous view', 'previous view' will be 'next view'. so I have to change frame accordingly.

Comment: Set the content size of the scroll view to `10 * <page size>`; content view would be a view with the same size (`10 * <page size>`) and it would contain 3 subviews (previous, current, next) with frames dynamically updated during scrolling as described in my answer. Please see [this tutorial](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/) to learn how to implement page scrolling with `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Thanks friend for your reply. I will definitely try this solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use UICollectionView in order to do that. 
You don't need to create your own flow layout - just use UICollectionViewFlowLayout, and change the item size and scroll direction.

Comment: with the use of custom collectionViewCell you can do this
just set height and Width of collectionViewCell's as the screen
and set FlowLayout to horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use UICollectionView. Pros?

1. Easier to add/remove additional pages. What if you'd like to change order, etc.? ;)
2. Reusable elements (memory efficient).
3. Easy to design in IB.

EDIT:
UICollectionView uses UIScrollViewDelegate as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use **DMLazyScrollView** library.

I'm using it frequently, and it's just work as you want :)

https://github.com/malcommac/DMLazyScrollView